# Are the single-atom holmium magnets developed at IBM an example of 'spintronics'?

Tags: quantum-spin, magnetic-moment, ferromagnetism

Phys.org IBM researchers create world's smallest magnet

The above article talks about using single, individual holmium atoms in one of two states (spin-up or spin-down? Or just north-pole-up vs. down?)
in future computers...

Is this an example of so-called 'spintronics'?

Comment: I don't think you added the link right. It just appears to be normal text in the first line

Comment: I don't think it qualifies as spintronics. Wikipedia says "Spintronics (a portmanteau meaning spin transport electronics[1][2][3]), also known as spin electronics, is the study of the intrinsic spin of the electron and its associated magnetic moment, in addition to its fundamental electronic charge, in solid-state devices.[4]". I am assuming "individual holmium atoms" means that the atoms are not in solid-state devices. However, the Wikipedia definition seems to require that solid-state devices have to be involved.